# Twitter integration using oAuth error

Tags: twitter, oauth, integration, titanium, nsexception

Hello
I have tried to post a tweet from my application. When I press on the button "post tweet" the authentication window (login window by twitter) opens, but when it is loaded my application just exits.

The following error occurs in the log;

```
[ERROR] Error Domain=com.google.GDataXML Code=-1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GDataXML error -1.)". in -[TiDOMDocumentProxy parseString:] (TiDOMDocumentProxy.m:50)
```

And in the end it says

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException
```

The code I used is:

```
var oAuthAdapter = new OAuthAdapter('SECRET KEY', 'KEY', 'HMAC-SHA1');


    // load the access token for the service (if previously saved)
    oAuthAdapter.loadAccessToken('twitter');

    oAuthAdapter.loadAccessToken('twitter');

    oAuthAdapter.send('https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json', [['status', 'Tweet from appcelerator ' + Math.random()]], 'Twitter', 'Published.', 'Not published.');

    if (oAuthAdapter.isAuthorized() == false) {
        // this function will be called as soon as the application is authorized 
        var receivePin = function(){
            // get the access token with the provided pin/oauth_verifier
            oAuthAdapter.getAccessToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token');
            // save the access token
            oAuthAdapter.saveAccessToken('twitter');
        };
        // show the authorization UI and call back the receive PIN function 

        oAuthAdapter.showAuthorizeUI('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize' +
        oAuthAdapter.getRequestToken('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'), receivePin);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

The line

```
 oAuthAdapter.showAuthorizeUI('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize'
```

Should be

```
 oAuthAdapter.showAuthorizeUI('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great to hear it is sorted. You can accept your own answer by clicking the hollow checkmark next to the up/down arrows on this answer.  When you have a chance, take an opportunity to read through the FAQ @ http://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

Use This code instead of above two lines of showAuthorization and getRequestToken

```
oAuthAdapter.showAuthorizeUI('https://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' +
oAuthAdapter.getRequestToken('https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token', 
[['oauth_callback', 'oob']]), receivePin, PinFinder.twitter);
```